# HTTP POST size limited to 2GB

Tags: php, linux, apache, http

I have an HTML form that is POSTing batches of images to a server using PHP, but I can't seem to find some dratted setting that is limiting user posts to 2GB. Files will post fine up to 2GB, but after that point, the server stops accepting files.

The $_FILES array that is posted contains all the original file names, but the `$_FILES['file']['size']` value is `0` for the image that would have put the total over 2GB as well as anything after it. `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` is also empty.

Settings I have changed already:

My vhost conf file:

```
<Directory /path/to/the/stuff>
  # LimitRequestBody 0 # this didn't do anything
  <Limit GET PUT POST>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from my.ip.add.range
   Deny from all
  </Limit>
  <IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_admin_value post_max_size 5000M
    php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 200M
    php_admin_value max_file_uploads 500
    php_admin_value memory_limit 512M
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Output of `phpinfo()` confirms all these settings.

At the top of the relevant php script:

`ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);`

This is on a RedHat Enterprise Linux server (`cat /etc/redhat-release` -> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago))

Is there some other mysterious setting that Google is hiding from me?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

These are 100MB+ master tif images, and we have hundreds (thousands?) to ingest, so breaking the uploads into smaller chunks ([as the code is written](https://github.com/BAM-PFA/piction-metadoodler)) is not feasible. I will be shooting for ~5GB total as a compromise limit, since most batches will be at or under that...

**UPDATE**:

As pointed out in @TheRealJAG's comment, it was a simple disk usage problem. Running `df` during a large upload showed that `/tmp` reached 100% (of 2027408 1-K blocks) really fast.

Now I just hope our admin will let us increase the tmp storage space!!

Or actually I will change the php /tmp setting in my script (`putenv('TMPDIR=/path/to/dir');`)

**SOLVED:**

I added this line to the vhost config:

`php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /path/with/more/memory/available`

This is a directory writable by the Apache user, which is what is calling the script.

Comment: Verify you're not running out of storage space.

Comment: This is a huge amount of data for a single post request! I'd reconsider and look into chunking the uploads into much smaller parts.

Comment: @TheRealJAG Ahhh! I think that's it! I tried an upload I knew would be over 2GB and did a series of `df` commands, and damn,  `/tmp` went up and up and up reaaaal fast.

Comment: yes, `/tmp` is often set with a smallish amount of diskspace. If your own machine you can reallocate more space, if you have to have an admin do the work, it may or maynot be allowed. `df -m /tmp` will show you where you currently stand. Good luck.

Comment: 2GB is max(signed int32).  Some baked in limit somewhere?